# sorting records number and then alphabetically

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a series of around 12000 records with unique identifiers as follows:

```
1, 1S, 3AS, 1A, 1AS, 2, 2H, 2S, 3, 4, 4H, 2AS, 5, 6A, 101S, 101AS and so on.
```

I want it to be sorted as under:

```
1, 1A, 1AS, 1S, 2, 2AS, 2H, 2S, 3, 3AS, 4, 4H, 5, 6A, 101AH, 101S and so on.
```

It works as :

first sort it by prefixed number, then sort by first alphabet, then sort by second alphabet.

Comment: Use `natsort()` perhaps?

Comment: hi @frz3993 can you please elaborate with a solution?

Comment: shouldn't it be select * from table order by identifier asc?

Comment: @GriffiN No, the output of your query is: 1, 10, 10H, 10S, 11, 11H, 11S ... it means it bring in all the records with 1 in it.

Answer (score 1):

Sort by integer value first and then the column value.

Let's say your column name is alphanumeric,

```
SELECT alphanumeric
   FROM sorting_test
   ORDER BY CAST(alphanumeric as UNSIGNED), alphanumeric
```

Comment: @ITSagar Accept this as answer if its fine.